# python3.6.5 urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, centos7, urlopen

I installed python3.6.5 @ centOS 7 and make without error. but when i test for urlopen it raise error below:

`e*urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>*`

I suspect it may related https and i double confirmed i have installed openssl
->zlib-dev1

Any advise on it? Thanks

**The python3 code:**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
print(x.read())
```

**full error:**
./url_test.py

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./url_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 549, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _ca`enter code here`ll_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1388, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i figure out what is problem cause it. It caused by openssl-devel that i did not install it.

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

after completed the installation. double check

```
yum list installed|grep openssl
openssl-devel.x86_64       1:1.0.2k-12.el7     @rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
```

re-make

```
./configure
make
```

Test it again.Done

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when installing poetry. Fixed that by just copying these two `dll` files

1. `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`
2. `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`

from `..\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to `..\Anaconda3\DLLs directory`.